# What to do when the UK Tier 2 visa application is taking more than a year to be processed?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

In January 2016, a friend submitted an application for a UK Tier 2 visa. The first response from the Home Office indicated that the case was complicated, in response to an inquiry sent via a solicitor. The second response from the Home Office in October 2016 indicated that a decision would be communicated in 6-8 weeks.

As of January 2017, there is still nothing further, although the applicant has made inquiries via an MP.

Why would it take so long and what can one do?

Comment: VTC: the applicant has a solicitor and a complicated case... too broad, opinions only.

Comment: VTC: also since we don't even know half the story, impossible to answer.